# Configure a vhost on url-basis

Tags: debian, apache-http-server

Let's say I have my site `www.mysite.com` with it's vhost configured.

Is it possible to configure apache in a way that when someone access ton `www.mysite.com/site1` and other url such as www.mysite.com/sites1/folder1/folder2/doc.html, apache no longer look at the vhost of `www.mysite.com` but another vhost ?

If yes, is there any cons for www.mysite.com ?

Edit : after some research I found out that it is not possible to configure a vhost on url-basis. However, would that still possible to do that with the ports ?

I mean let's say I've got my subdomain site, so when I type `www.mysite.com/site1` it's redirected to `site.mysite.com` with a specific port so that's the vhost configured for the site1 that's concerned and so on...

It seems feasible though I still have no idea about how to specify the port in the redirection, what do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) that will allow yo to do all sorts of fancy redirects based on different conditions.

As a start this page might be good: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/

Hope it's getting you forward.